# How to convert a function defined inside document.ready() into global

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have read in other examples, that to access a function inside document.ready, we have to convert it into global.

But how to do it in this case, please help.

HTML:

```
<body onresize="myFunction()">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function myFunction()
{
alert("Stop resizing.");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4Dwd/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just move the function outside of $(document).ready?

Comment: This code that I posted, was a very abstracted form of my problem, in the original code I wan't to execute the function onload as well as when the window is resized.

Comment: Simply declare the function outside of document.ready, then call it wherever you need it.

Comment: So you're saying you would like to execute code on resize and pageload, if so you should ask for that as it has nothing to do with this. Generally only the window can be resized (with a few expections) not an element, so that makes the answers below rather useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses, but I figured another way round,

HTML:

```
<body onload="myFunction()" onresize="myFunction()">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction()
{
alert("Stop resizing.");
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4Dwd/6/

Worked for me, anyways thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

`$(document).ready()` is itself a function, so you are calling a function in a function.

Since your function `myfunction()` is fired when a button is clicked, you don't need to wrap that function in `$(document).ready()` as `$(document).ready()` contains self executing commands which needs to be put on hold before DOM loads.

So, in brief,

HTML:

```
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
alert("Stop resizing.");
}
```

Edit:

I saw that you said you want function to execute onclick as well as when the window is resized.

In that case,

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
alert("Stop resizing.");
}
$(window).resize(function() {
myFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access a function inside document.ready, Here is the code-

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     window.myFunction = function myFunction()
      {
        alert("Stop resizing.");
      }
  });
```

Make it global using window.{functionName}. Try it, its working.

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Dwd/4/).If i understand you correctly.I have changed the code and you can access it changing your function name like this

```
$.myFunction= function(){
alert("Stop resizing.");
}
```

then you can call the function like

```
$.myFunction()
```

Hope that helps.